# Inserting into vector doesn't insert values

Tags: c++, stl

I don't know why it doesn't work. I tried to do it with push_back and it doesn't work either.

When I try to debug it I get error:

> GeneticAlgorithm(8942,0x7fffc40183c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1059546636242944) failed (error code=3)
>   *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

I also tried to resize vectorOfIndividuals but then I get BAD_ACCESS ERROR

```
    Population children(population);
    population.getVectorOfIndividuals().insert(population.getVectorOfIndividuals().begin(),children.getVectorOfIndividuals().begin(),children.getVectorOfIndividuals().end());
```

Population copying constructor:

```
Population::Population(const Population &populationToSave){
vectorOfIndividuals = populationToSave.vectorOfIndividuals;
bestFitnessScore = populationToSave.bestFitnessScore;
```

}

Getter:

```
vector<Individual> Population::getVectorOfIndividuals(){
return vectorOfIndividuals;
```

}

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Short answer seems to be that you ran out of memory. Not sure what OS or machine you're on (iOS?), but the size in `mach_vm_map(size=1059546636242944) failed` looks hard to satisfy (963+ TiB) by mortal hardware. On what part of this code does it actually fail? I'm guessing the `population.getVectorofIndividuals().insert(...)` call? It strikes me that vector will grow pretty quickly on each iteration, since `children` itself is initialized from `population`, but I don't know the API you're using.

Comment: @OliverSeiler It's strange because `children` contains only 5 elements. I'm using Clion on MacOS.

Comment: `vector<Individual> Population::getVectorOfIndividuals()` will get you a fresh new **copy** of the vector for each call. Any changes will be lost immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Your getter must return a reference, not a copy:

```
vector<Individual>& Population::getVectorOfIndividuals()
{
    return vectorOfIndividuals;
}
```

Else, when you do:

```
population.getVectorOfIndividuals().insert(population.getVectorOfIndividuals().begin(),children.getVectorOfIndividuals().begin(),children.getVectorOfIndividuals().end());
```

You mix different objects together (you insert to one, at the beginning of another...as every call to `population.getVectorOfIndividuals()` returns a different `vector<Individual>` object: it's like doing `vectorA.insert(vectorB.begin(),vectorC.begin(),vectorC.end())`, which is not valid...`vectorA` and `vectorB` must be the same object).

Comment: Yeah, that was about reference, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
vector<Individual> Population::getVectorOfIndividuals()
```

returns vector instance by value, which means every time you call this method a new copy is created. So first of all you pass `begin()` of another vector for which you call insert and `begin()` and `end()` of children also iterators for 2 different containers. Also result of `insert` would be dropped even if you pass parameters properly. Most probably you want that method to return `vector<Individual>` by reference.